# Why would SQL Server 2012 SP1 installer fail when ran within a Burn boostraped setup?

Tags: windows, wix, installation, burn, sql-server-2012-express

I have a WiX *Bundle* that has an SQL Server 2012 SP1 ExePackage which correctly installs SQL Server in a VM. When booting the machine from a [VHD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VHD_%28file_format%29) with the same OS that works in the VM, the setup fails, yet when I run the command line specified in the ExePackage, I have no problems and SQL Server gets installed correctly.

What could be running within the bootstrapper be changing for the SQL Server setup?

This is the ExePackage:

```
<ExePackage
    Id               = "SqlServerExpress"
    Cache            = "no"
    Compressed       = "no"
    PerMachine       = "yes"
    Permanent        = "yes"
    Vital            = "yes"
    Name             = "redist\SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe"
    InstallCommand   = "/ACTION=Install /UPDATEENABLED=false /INSTANCENAME=$(var.SqlInstanceName) /FEATURES=SQLEngine /QS /HIDECONSOLE /ROLE=ALLFeatures_WithDefaults /SKIPRULES=RebootRequiredCheck /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS=BUILTIN\Administrators /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS"
    RepairCommand    = "/ACTION=Repair  /UPDATEENABLED=false /INSTANCENAME=$(var.SqlInstanceName) /FEATURES=SQLEngine /QS /HIDECONSOLE"
    DownloadUrl      = "$(var.SqlDownloadUrl_x64)"
    InstallCondition = "VersionNT64"
    DetectCondition  = "SqlServerInstanceInstalled"
>
```

**Updated**: The setup [logs](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2200654/SO/20130702_133802.zip).

Comment: Checking the logs of the SQL Server installation, the process appears to get stuck trying to connect to the newly installed server using a pipe...maybe something in the way the process gets created doesn't allow connection using a pipe to the new SQL server instance?

Comment: It appears that passing /NPENABLED=0 to disable named pipes solves the problem, yet the question still stands...what could be the problem of running within the bootstrapper?

Comment: I spoke too early, the /NPENABLED=0 didn't solve the problem (it did work once, but it is not reliable)...=(

Comment: What errors are you getting when it fails?

Comment: @caveman_dick I've added the logs to the question. Hopefully you'll see something I've missed! =)

Comment: Had a quick look and although I can't say whether this is the problem, but the Sql Browser is set to start disabled. I know you don't need it for a default instance but as soon as you change the instance name it can cause connectivity issues. Might be worth investigating why this is happening, it may fix your issue.

Comment: I'll try that, but the thing that bothers me is that this works correctly from the command line (as well as from the installer when run in a VM).